# Will the TVS diode work if a high alternating voltage accidentally gets into the circuit?

Tags: tvs

I have a controller with power lines 220V / 12V / 5V.
The 220 V line is well insulated from low voltage circuits. On the 12 V line, a TVS [P6SMB16CA](https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS_Diode_P6SMB_Datasheet.pdf-365562.pdf) diode is connected.

What happens if 220 V accidentally hits the 12 V line?
Will the TVS diode trip with an AC line fuse? Can the diode protect the circuit so that the dangerous voltage does not go beyond it?

Comment: Only during the time before it overheats and explodes. Its meant for ESD, surges and ligtning, not significant and continuous overvoltage.

Comment: The 220V should be really well insulated from the low voltage circuits, not *only* because of the issue of the circuit protection. Humans are susceptible to 220V, too.